# How do I invoke AWS Rekognition from a Lambda within a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-rekognition

I am working on a lambda function that needs to access `RDS`, `S3` and `Rekognition` services from AWS.

I gave `S3` and `Rekognition` permissions via the `AmazonS3FullAccess` and the `AmazonRekognitionFullAccess` policies respectively and it worked fine

The thing is that I could not access my `Aurora` instance inside `RDS` because it's inside a VPC

I changed my lambda network configurations so it would be able to access the VPC, and the `Aurora` connection worked as expected, but then the connection to `Rekognition` stopped working, whenever I invoke `detectLabels` for example it just hangs.

Am I missing some permission?

Comment: Can the lambda access _anything_ outside the VPC?

Comment: How can I test that? I'm sort of learning Lambda as I go

Comment: Try opening a http connection to the internet from the lambda.

Comment: I tried accessing `http://www.google.com` and it hung as well, apparently no outside connection is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have no outside connection then you'll need to create an internet gateway through the VPC via NAT.

AWS has [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) for it, and there's a bit more discussion in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448692/access-aws-resource-outside-of-vpc-from-within-vpc-serverless-framework).